Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project "<My_Project_name>"
I'm trying to import the existing Java maven project after an Eclipse & JDK fresh install. After importing the Java project, I'm getting the following error.

OS --- Windows 11
Eclipse ver --- Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
JDK ver --- Java 21


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/pde/internal/core/natures/PDE
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.annotations.OSGiAnnotationsCompilationParticipant.isActive(OSGiAnnotationsCompilationParticipant.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$CompilationParticipants.getCompilationParticipants(JavaModelManager.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.initializeBuilder(JavaBuilder.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.natures.PDE cannot be found by org.eclipse.pde.ui_3.15.0.v20231118-2008
    ... 17 more

Tried few solutions like Cleaning project, mvn clean, prioritizing the configure builder path, etc.

Have you tried the current release?

The PDE class should be present in 4.30, it has been dropped in the current 4.33 so it is not clear what is happening here.

Please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

First of all, Thanks to @howlger! Because of you, I got the clue that the issue is with Eclipse.
There were duplicate folders of the same eclipse version present in 'C:\Users<Username>\eclipse'.
Then, I delete one of them. Restarted eclipse. The issue got fixed.
